# Querying Access database vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, ms-access, querying

I am trying to figure out how to query an access database to take info from the database and put it into a class array. I know how to do some querying using basic LINQ, but not sure how to do it the way I want it to. I have a character class I am using, I am storing all the character traits in a database. I want to query the database and add that info to a class array.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here at the class private variables which are the same traits in the database:

```
    Public Class Character
        Private _strName As String
        Private _intLevel As Integer
        Private _intHealth As Integer
        Private _intDamage As Integer
        Private _intScore As Integer
```

Comment: Look into OleDbConnection & OleDbCommand classes. They will help you connect to and query your Access DB.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. I have to say this is not a good question.
Actually what you are saying is...: Please build me the dataconnections for this acces database and a visual studio form.

But because I'm in a good mood, That's what I did for you.

I created a little database file in acces.I saved it into a folder called database. Which is located in the project directory.

I made 2 classes. 1 CharactersForm, and 2 Gateway

the gateway is to make an connection to your Acces database.
The CharactersForm is the form what you see when you debug

Here is the CharactersForm class.
Make sure you drag and drop a listbox and a button
Call the listbox ListBoxCharacters.
Call the button InladenButton. Or call it whatever you want, But make sure it will fit the code given.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

    Public Class CharactersForm

        Dim _CharactersGateway As New Gateway

        Private Sub InladenButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InladenButton.Click
            _CharactersGateway.LoadDataTableCharacters()

            ListBoxCharacters.DataSource = _CharactersGateway.CharactersDataTable

            ListBoxCharacters.DisplayMember = "Name"

        End Sub
    End Class
```

The Gateway Class ( to make connection to your acces file)
If somehow visual studio cannot reach the database then it means the connectionstring is not correct. Make sure the connection string is exactly as where your accesfile.accdb is located

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer On

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Gateway

    Public Shared AppPath As String = Application.StartupPath()
    '\Debug
    Public Shared DirectoryUp1 As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppPath)
    '\bin
    Public Shared DirectoryUp2 As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(DirectoryUp1)
    '\CharactersStackOverFlow
    Public Shared DirectoryUp3 As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(DirectoryUp2)
    '\CharactersStackOverFlow
    Public Shared AccesDatabaseFilePath As String = DirectoryUp3 & "\DataBase\Characters.accdb"

    Dim ConnectionString As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & AccesDatabaseFilePath)

    Public Property DataSetCharacters As New DataSet

    Public ReadOnly Property CharactersDataTable As DataTable
        Get
            CharactersDataTable = DataSetCharacters.Tables("Characters")
        End Get
    End Property
    Public CharactersDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter

    Public Sub LoadDataTableCharacters()

        CharactersDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Characters", ConnectionString)

        CharactersDataAdapter.Fill(DataSetCharacters, "Characters")
        Dim kamersCommandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(CharactersDataAdapter)

    End Sub

End Class
```

This is as Yuriy Galanter said. You need the OleDbConnection.
If you are using office 2010 and you get thsi warning ::

```
'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine
```

You need to download the 2007 Office System Driver. It works also for 2010 don't ask me why.

Type '2007 Office System Driver' in google. And from microsoft you can download and install it.

ALL DONE!

if you run the program and press the load button. The names of your characters will come in the listbox.

If you want to put values of the fields of the database in variables. Then it's just about making a for loop and put them in dimmed variables. That is something I'm sure you can do yourself. The connection to the database and the loading in the program is already sorted out now!

Good luck

Jonathan